# Sign-up wizard structure seems too repetitive

Tags: javascript, angular.js

I think my current structure is way too repetitive.  I feel like I must be missing something that would easily make this sign up wizard work far better.

```
  <ol class="registerMeter">
    <li class="progress-point" ng-click="wiz('step1')"     ng-class="{active: step1.active, done: step1.done, todo: step1.todo}">Step 1</li>
    <li class="progress-point" ng-click="wiz('step2')"     ng-class="{active: step2.active, done: step2.done, todo: step2.todo}">Step 2</li>
    <li class="progress-point" ng-click="wiz('step3')"     ng-class="{active: step3.active, done: step3.done, todo: step3.todo}">Step 3</li>
</ol>
<section class="row formMain" ng-switch="step">
    <section class="row" ng-switch-default>
        <form ng-submit="registerSubmit()">                
        </form>        
    </section>
    <section ng-switch-when="step2">
        <form>

        </form>
    </section>
    <section ng-switch-when="step3">
        <form>

        </form>
    </section>
</section>


app.controller('registerCtrl', function($scope, $http, $location, FlashService){

    $scope.step1 = {active: true, done:false, todo: false};
    $scope.step2 = {active: false, done:false, todo: true};
    $scope.step3 = {active: false, done:false, todo: true};

    $scope.wiz = function(step){
        $scope.step = step;
        switch (step) {
            case 'step1':
                $scope.step1 = {active: true, done:false, todo: false};
                $scope.step2.active = false;
                $scope.step3.active = false;
                $scope.step2.todo = true;
                $scope.step3.todo = true;
                break;
            case 'step2':
                $scope.step1.active = false;
                $scope.step1.todo = true;
                $scope.step2 = {active: true, done:false, todo: false};                
                $scope.step3.active = false;
                $scope.step3.active = false;
                break;
            case 'step3':
                $scope.step1.active = false;
                $scope.step2.active = false;
                $scope.step1.todo = true;
                $scope.step2.todo = true;
                $scope.step3 = {active: true, done:false, todo: false};
                break
            default: 
                $scope.step1 = {active: true, done:false, todo: false};
                $scope.step2 = {active: false, done:false, todo: true};
                $scope.step3 = {active: false, done:false, todo: true};            
        }
    }



    $scope.registerSubmit = function(){
        $http.post()
            .success(function(data, status, headers, config){                
                $scope.step = 'step2';
                $scope.step1 = {active: false, done:true , todo:false}
                $scope.step2.active = true;
                if (data.msg !='') {
                      $scope.msgs.push(data.msg);
                  } else {
                       $scope.errors.push(data.error);
                   }
              }).error(function(data, status){
                      FlashService.show(response.flash);
                    $scope.errors.push(status);
                })
    };
});
```

I'm worried that the `switch` and `ngclass` statements are way more than I need. Is there a simpler way to accomplish this? This just doesn't feel DRY at all.

Comment: You have a lot of booleans Are they all required? Could you instead check if values the user enters in the wizard exist (not null) instead of three boolean states?

Comment: @Sukima That's interesting. I could check if the object from the form is user interacted yet. That would only work one way though and wouldn't allow a user to go back a step. It's a long sign up form.

Comment: In that case I think it would be better to wrap your boolean logic into a finite state machine object which manages the state the user is in. A little abstraction can help with readability.

Answer (score 2):

You can make this DRYer if you can assume that :

- You keep naming each step `stepx`
- No other variables in `$scope` start with `step`

In that case you could use a function that sets in a first step the right scope active and then the other steps inactive:

```
function updateScopeSteps( $scope , step )
{
   //Default to step1
   step = step || 'step1';
   //Set step
   $scope.step = step;
   //Activate step
   $scope[ step ] = {active: true, done:false, todo: false};
   //De-activate all other steps
   for( var name in $scope ){
     if( name.substring(0,4) == 'step' && name != step ){
       $scope[name].active = false;
       $scope[name].todo = true;
     }
   }
}
```